# What are TYPE_ORDER and TYPE_PAYMENT transactions?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

**\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionInterface** has several transaction types. While I do understand the association between *authorization*, *capture*, *void* and *refund* with the payment methods' commands, it's still a mystery for me what other two types (`TYPE_ORDER` and `TYPE_PAYMENT`) do.
I have found this method in `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment` where `TYPE_ORDER` used:

```
public function canCapture()
{
    if (!$this->getMethodInstance()->canCapture()) {
        return false;
    }
    // Check Authorization transaction state
    $authTransaction = $this->getAuthorizationTransaction();
    if ($authTransaction && $authTransaction->getIsClosed()) {
        $orderTransaction = $this->transactionRepository->getByTransactionType(
            Transaction::TYPE_ORDER,
            $this->getId(),
            $this->getOrder()->getId()
        );
        if (!$orderTransaction) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

From here, it is not clear for me:

1. What `TYPE_ORDER` transaction represents?
2. Why it is required to decide whether payment method allowed to capture?
3. What is the relation between *authorization* and *order* transactions?

Comment: Wow, I just stumbled today on the exact same question and the exact same piece of code. I'm guessing you were also trying to get the dropdown visible in the admin area to "capture online"? Did you ever find an answer on your own question?

Comment: @GielBerkers I didn't. But if you want to see "capture online" you have to make sure that Authorize payment has transaction ID (`setTransactionId()`) and the transaction is not closed (`setIsTransactionClosed(false)`). These are methods of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I visited Meet Magento in the Netherlands (2019), I spoke to 2 developers: 1 core developer of the PayPal platform and 1 extension developer of Ayden. I asked them about the transaction of type `TYPE_ORDER`, and the only satisfying answer I got was that from the PayPal developer:

It appears that 'order' is a PayPal specific thing (see also https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/auth-capture/#orders-and-order-authorizations). It looks like Magento inherited this type of transaction even though no other payment methods use it. Hence it's a bit strange that if an authorization is closed, an order transaction is required to be able to do a capture online.

Like @ualinker stated in the comment on the original question, making sure that the authorization transaction is not closed will allow an online capture. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082042/1471590

> In Magento, the is_closed flag signifies that a transaction is settled and no other operations may be performed against it. The reason a transaction would be left open until settlement is so that you can do partial shipments of goods (multiple captures), as well as void or refund the transaction.

So in case of an authorization, the transaction should not be closed, otherwise you cannot do a (partial) capture on it. By default the `is_closed`-flag is set to `1` (defined in the database scheme), so this means that unless you explicitly mark a transaction as 'open', it will be closed by default.\

So the short answer would be: to be able to do an online capture on an authorized transaction, make sure that you the authorized transaction is not (yet) closed.